# Network Query for Logged In User - Salesforce Mobile SDK

Tags: soql, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, react-native

Unable to find any documentation on obtaining the logged in User's Id from the Salesforce Mobile SDK for React Native.

In apex the following would work:

```
select Id, username from User where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()
```

And the network { net } import for salesforce mobile sdk can handle queries, but it cannot understand UserInfo.getUserId().

Mobile SDK Docs: https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/mobile_sdk.pdf

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Based on SFDCFox's answer, how would I capture the this Id endpoint URL from the follow authentication:

```
    componentDidMount() {
      var that = this;
      oauth.getAuthCredentials(
          () => that.fetchData(), // already logged in
          () => {
              oauth.authenticate(
                  () => that.fetchData(),
                  (error) => console.log('Failed to authenticate:' + error)
              );
          });
  }

fetchData() {
  var that = this;
  net.query('SELECT Id, Name, Email, Phone FROM User LIMIT 10',
            (response) => that.setState({data: response.records})
           );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you log in with the Mobile SDK, your auth callback will include an identity URL in the `id` attribute. It'll look something like `https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D.../005...`. You can then query this URL directly to get a ton of user details. You can read more about it in [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/oauth_using_identity_urls.htm). There's no specific SOQL call you can use, but it's not necessary, since there is an alternative method.

Comment: Thanks! I thought it would have the Id in the response, didn't expect it to be an endpoint though. This may be off-topic, but I have added the authentication code, how would I capture that response given callback function fetchData() above?

Comment: @S.B. I'm not particularly a mobile developer, I just know enough to be marginally dangerous. I think a normal XMLHttpRequest could be used on it, though.